# loops and Factorial calculation in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am just starting to learn c#. I tried calculating factorial function for a number. The number of times the loop runs is out of my understanding. here is the code for the function.

```
 static int func(int p)
 {
     int l = 1;
     while(p>0)
     {
         l = l*p;
          p--;
     }
  }
```

Comment: The number of loop runs is P. Every turn of loop, p = p-1; (p--;) runs when p is 0 loop breaks.

Comment: FYI - your function has no return, so won't compile.  It will also produce incorrect results for `p` > 12, since it will overflow `l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the explanation.

`int l` = 1 //Because is the initial number

`while (p > 0)` //THis means that while the number you want to get the factorial is bigger than 0,                     everything inside the loop will execute

Imagine that p = 3, then:

`1st time` - l * 3 = 3. and substract -1 to p.

`2nd time` - Now, p = 2, then l * 2 = 6, and substract -1 to p.

`3rd time` - Now, p = 1, then l ? 1 = 6, and substact -1 to p.

Now p = 0, then the loop will end.

**Number of times the while loop has been executed are 3 if p = 3.

If p = 10, times will be 10.**

Your function will be something like this:

```
public int GetFactorial(int number)
 {
     int start = 1;
     while(number > 0)
     {
         start = start * number;
         number--;
     }
     return start;
  }
```

Better now? :)

Comment: its not working @Oscar Bralo its more or less the same code as now.. i just forgot to mention the return statement but it doesnt work even with that. The result is still 0.

Comment: Is working for me. Copy the code of my comment. Or only add the return to your code.

Comment: worked for me too. I made some other mistake in second time. Thanks.

Comment: Great!! mark as correct answer if it helped for you, in order to help other people too ;) i am glad to help you!